# How to make jar write/read to external file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar, path

my jar is meant to read and write to a .json file. To do this, I've decided to have an external file to read from and to write to.

My jar is created via docker-compose up and runs in /a/b/c/d/app.jar

The .json file that I want to interact with is in /homeDir/Documents/file.json

```
JSONObject aJQLs = new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream("/Documents/file.json"), "UTF-8"));
```

However, I keep getting FileNotFoundException.

**I thought this would've been as simple as just entering the absolute path to the file.**

I get the following error log

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'jiraAutomationController' defined in URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-
INF/classes!/com/company/jiraautomation/controller/JiraAutomationController.class]: Instantiation of bean 
failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate 
[com.company.jiraautomation.controller.JiraAutomationController]: Constructor threw exception; nested 
exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Documents/file.json (No such file or directory)
```

Is it possible for the jar to interact with an external file the way I want it to?

Is there something wrong with my understanding of file paths when running a jar?

I did a quick test without Spring Boot, just normal Java to see if maybe I was wrong with my path logic, but it worked fine.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you share how are you access this automation_jql.json

Comment: automation_jql.json is the same as file.json. Sorry about that, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are running your jar from inside a docker container it will not be able to access any files on the host system as docker container run in an isolation with host operating system.

However, you can mount the volumes from host system to your docker container.

**Docker host-mounted volumes**

Syntax: /host/path:/container/path

Host path can be defined as an absolute or as a relative path.

Example:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - /var/opt/my_website/dist:/usr/share/nginx/html
```

In your case you can add following to your `docker-compose.yml` to related service -

```
volumes:
  - /homeDir/Documents:/user/local/Documents
```

Now your /`homeDir/Documents` on host OS will be mounted to `/user/local/Documents` on container (`/user/local/Documents` this directory will be automatically created by docker). After this modify your java code to read the file from location inside the to the container i.e `/user/local/Documents/file.json` (as defined in volumes) like this -

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream("/user/local/Documents/file.json"), "UTF-8"));
```

Now your program should be able to read the file from the host OS by using docker volumes.

Answer (score 0):

Change your path to

```
"file:///Documents/file.json"
```

then try.